# Upload large file via URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsurlsession

So I have some code I've been using to upload files in my app, along the lines of this:

```
var mutableURLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
var uploadData = try! Data(contentsOf: dataUrl)
session.uploadTask(with: mutableURLRequest, from: uploadData).resume()
```

There's a little more to it than that, but those are the relevant parts.  However I've noticed for some large video files `Data(contentsOf: dataUrl)` fails since the file is to big to load into memory.  I want to restructure this so that I'm able to stream piece by piece to the server without ever having to load the whole file into memory.

I already have this figured out from my server, the only piece I haven't figured out is how to get a `chunkSize` piece from the data in a URL, without putting it into a data object.  I essentially want this construct:

```
let chunkSize = 1024 * 1024
let offset = 0
let chunk = //get data from dataUrl of size chunkSize offset by offset

//Upload each chunk and increment offset
```

`NSInputStream` seemed promising in being able to do this, but I wasn't able to figure out the minimum set up in order to pull bytes from a file on disk in this fashion.  What code can I use above to fill in the `let chunk =` line to do such a task?

Comment: Did you try `uploadTask(with:fromFile:)`? It might be smart enough to stream from the file as opposed to loading the whole thing into `Data`. Or maybe use `uploadTask(withStreamedRequest:)`.

Comment: I'm guessing that isn't going to work for me since I need to decorate each chunk with some other HTTP junk so my server knows what's going on.  However, whatever it's using under the covers to do that may be what I need.

Comment: I did some testing of `uploadTask(with:fromFile:)` and can confirm that it **does not** load the whole file into memory! This ended up being the perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working solution, might need a little tweaking, but seems to work for big files I've tried:

```
public func getNextChunk() -> Data?{
    if _inputStream == nil {
        _inputStream = InputStream(url: _url)
        _inputStream?.open()
    }
    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: CHUNK_SIZE)
    var len = _inputStream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: CHUNK_SIZE)
    if len == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return Data(buffer)
}
```

I also call `_inputStream?.close()` on deinit of my class that manages the chunking of a file on disk.

Comment: Cool! But how would you send these peaces to your server one by one? Would you create a separate request for each chunk or is there a smarter/efficient way?